# Angular 7 datepicker timezones

Tags: javascript, angular, timezone, momentjs

I'm using Angular material components. For datepicker I set MomentDateAdapter.

Now want to work with different timezones in my app.

I know the timezone id based on the logged-in user.

Is there any possibility to set datepicker to work with the given timezone?

I imported  moment-timezone package to work with timezones and set default timezone for moment globally via `moment.tz.setDefault(timezone)`, when I call `moment().tz(timezone).format()` I get the correct moment date with the expected timezoneinfo. However, I select a date from DatePicker I always get a date in timezone according to browser settings.

Do you have any idea what do I wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The current implementation of the moment adapter for the material date picker will always write back a local moment instance. You can always apply any timezone you wish to that returned instance though in your own code logic. If you want additional help please describe exactly what it is you are trying to do because it is not clear (to me).

Comment: If you really wanted a different variation of this you can create (override) you own moment date adapter and use that.

Comment: @Igor I want to get a response from datepicker like "2019-09-23T00:00:00-0500" according to timezone settings

Comment: So you still have 2 options like I stated. Either apply `tz(timezone)` to the selected date after selection or before processing (whatever). Alternatively you can create you own date adapter for the material date picker and apply it there.